# postfix smtpd_restriction_classes not working

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to restrict who can send emails on a server.
I use this directive in main.cf:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

Content of /etc/mailname is:

```
cassiopeia.caoba.fr
```

Content of /etc/postfix/sender_access is:

```
santiago@cassiopeia.caoba.fr   REJECT
```

Of course the hashfile was created with:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sender_access
```

And postfix was restarted with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Still, santiago is still perfectly able to send emails. Example:

```
echo $RANDOM | mail -s "Test" my_personnal_address@gmail.com
```

My main.cf file is:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
smtp_generic_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/generic
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost localhost.$mydomain $myhostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter =
smtp_sasl_security_options =
relayhost = mail.authsmtp.com:2525
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

Content of

Comment: Please show the mail.log entries corresponding to an email that was delivered but that you expected to be blocked. Also please consider upgrading to Debian stable.

Answer (score 1):

`mail` doesn't use `SMTP` protocol so `smtpd_sender_restrictions` doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. What does mail use to send messages then? How does it manage to send messages through my smtp paid service with the password that is only given in /etc/postfix/main.cf ?

Comment: @Chebarbudo `mail` uses system `sendmail` to submit a message to `postfix` queue, then `postfix` uses `SMTP` to deliver the message to external servers. `smtpd_sender_restrictions` apply only to incoming `SMTP` sessions on your `postfix` system.

Comment: Thanks @AlexD, it's clearer now in my mind.
How could I prevent user santiago from submiting a mail to postfix then?